# Compare text within two Cells in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at VBA Programming and was hoping if someone can help with this. I have been reading some other post but too complicated for me to understand at my level.

I am trying to compare two cells in Excel and trying to match words within both of the Cells and see if there are any words matching between them. [(see picture for reference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2bVF.png)

Comment: Please review [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the best help on this site going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small *UDF()*:

```
Public Function WhatsInCommon(A As String, B As String) As String
    arya = Split(LCase(A), " ")
    aryb = Split(LCase(B), " ")

    WhatsInCommon = ""
    For Each aa In arya
        For Each bb In aryb
            If aa = bb Then
                If WhatsInCommon = "" Then
                    WhatsInCommon = aa
                Else
                    WhatsInCommon = WhatsInCommon & "," & aa
                End If
            End If
        Next bb
    Next aa
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

*Notes:*

1. assumes that a "word" is a string of characters encapsulated by a space
2. converts to lower case

**EDIT#1:**

This version will only consider words greater than two character:

```
Public Function WhatsInCommon(A As String, B As String) As String
    arya = Split(LCase(A), " ")
    aryb = Split(LCase(B), " ")

    WhatsInCommon = ""
    For Each aa In arya
        If Len(aa) > 2 Then
            For Each bb In aryb
                If aa = bb Then
                    If WhatsInCommon = "" Then
                        WhatsInCommon = aa
                    Else
                        WhatsInCommon = WhatsInCommon & "," & aa
                    End If
                End If
            Next bb
        End If
    Next aa
End Function
```

Comment: I added to my file and works perfectly just what I needed. Thank you very much... One question? is there any way to limit the search for >2 Characters. I want to eliminate the function to give me the or, is, in, on (for larger texts). Appreciate the support !!